# Why is Pandas not letting me select a specific column within a dataframe even when that column name definitely does exist?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to display the output of one column in my data frame but keep getting a KeyError: 'Title'

Here is my code as well as what the csv file looks like in excel:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv(r'file\path\output.csv')
    df = pd.DataFrame(df)
    print (df)
    #Below allows you to view all column names
    for col in df.columns: 
        print(col) 
    df.columns.str.strip()
    df.groupby(['Title'])
```

The last line of code is not printing out the Title column of the data frame and

I'm recieving a

> KeyError: "Title" error.

Comment: just put the df.head() here in post

Comment: Need to assign it back `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()`. Also no need for `df = pd.DataFrame(df)`, reading it in returns a DataFrame.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is helpful to view all the columns in a list to spot differences like trailing spaces in the column names.  Make sure 'Title' exists using:

```py
list(df)
```

I generally call the list rather than printing each column name because I want to see the white space within the quotes.